# Append Google Maps URL with Current Location

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, xcode6, core-location, messageui

I am trying to compose an email with a Google Maps link using Core Location and MessageUI. Presently my code produces this string: https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=0.000000,0.000000.
I would like to append the device's longitude and latitude with the URL.
Here is my implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController{
NSString *currentLongitude;
NSString *currentLatitude;
NSString *googleMapsURL;
CLLocationManager *locationManager_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

locationManager_ = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager_.delegate = self;
locationManager_.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager_.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager_ requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[locationManager_ startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (IBAction)composeMailButton:(id)sender {

NSString *bodyHeader = @"Here are you directions:";
NSString *mailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", bodyHeader, googleMapsURL];

MFMailComposeViewController *emailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[emailComposer setSubject:@"Google Maps Directions"];
[emailComposer setMessageBody:mailBody isHTML:NO];
[emailComposer setToRecipients:@[@"castro.michael87@gmail.com"]];
[emailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

[self presentViewController:emailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
NSString *googleMapsURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

I am guessing that I have not correctly implemented the locationManager. Any input is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make use that you added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your `info.plist` file.

[image]

Second, your viewController need to implement the `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`

```
@interface ViewController ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Third, setup your `locationManager` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
    locationManager_ = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager_.delegate = self;
    locationManager_.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager_.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager_ requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager_ startUpdatingLocation];
```

Fourth, implement the `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSString *googleMapsURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"%@", googleMapsURL);
}
```

Finally, if you test in simulator, you need to simulate a location:

[image]

Code Snippet: https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/b1be760596da54873f81

Comment: I have implemented these suggestions and the code above reflects these edits. However, my message body now prints: "(null)".

Comment: You never assign a value to your instant variable `NSString *googleMapsURL;`, instead you create a local variable inside the `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations ` method. So, you should change the last line in your didUpdateLocations method to `googleMapsURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];`

Comment: Will I be able to use the googleMapsURL variable in my composeMailButton? I have it defined as a local variable now, and my message still prints"(null)" for the URL. Thanks again

Comment: I do believe that I have implemented the same code from the snippet and still I see no URL in the message body. Here I tried to create a repository for the project: [MessengerDemo](https://github.com/FIDELHIMSELF/MessengerDemoProject). Please take a look if you can.

Comment: The line before the last closing curly brace is different... See it closely, mine has no NSStrimg*